# LibGDX app works on Desktop, black screen on Android

Tags: android, libgdx

[Source on GitHub](https://github.com/shvelo/gdxgame)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9733.jpg)

I'm trying to make a game with Tiled map support on Android, the desktop build works fine,
but on Android it shows a black screen, with no errors in LogCat. My device supports GLES2.0 and is running Android 4.4.

I've tried reducing the number of layers in the tile map and making it smaller, no effect.

[LogCat output](http://hastebin.com/zemulijefo.md)

Init method:

```
    w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    tileW = w / 64f;
    tileH = h / 64f;

    x = tileW;
    y = tileH;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, w / 64f, h / 64f);
    camera.zoom = 2;
    camera.update();

    assetManager = new AssetManager();

    map = loadMap();

    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1f / 64f);
```

Render method:

```
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(100f / 255f, 100f / 255f, 250f / 255f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(viewResized()) resetCamera();

    calculateSpeed();

    //updating camera position

    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();
```

Map loading:

```
    assetManager.setLoader(TiledMap.class, new TmxMapLoader(new InternalFileHandleResolver()));
    assetManager.load("map.tmx", TiledMap.class);

    assetManager.finishLoading();
    map = assetManager.get("map.tmx");

    MapProperties prop = map.getProperties();

    //Calculate some stuff from properties

    return map;
```

Comment: Likely due to an unsupported texture format. How big is your texture(s)?

Comment: @Tenfour04 It's a single 2560 x 1664 png tileset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was caused by the texture size, the tileset was too large.